# processing.run wont work with filter on layer

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a pyqgis script in my plugin. There I like to execute a process:

```
new = processing.run("native:splitwithlines", {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition('table-path-to-the-db', selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid), 'LINES':rot_line,'OUTPUT':'memory:new'})['OUTPUT']
```

It works well. But when I have a filter on this layer I get an error:

> Unable to execute algorithm
>
> Could not load source layer for INPUT: table-path-to-the-db not found

Why is it like this? What do I have to change for working with filters?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I need to change the path to my table into dynamically. Thus I have an filter on the layer, the source is also changing. Before I start the process I define the source by new...

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_to_split')[0]
source = layer.source()

new = processing.run("native:splitwithlines", {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(source, selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid), 'LINES':rot_line,'OUTPUT':'memory:new'})['OUTPUT']
```